# Make Windows Logo Appear on Boot

Tags: windows-10

Instead of the windows logo appearing on boot, it just has the OEM logo with the loading icon under it. Is there a way to make it the Windows logo?

Comment: You may be able to select the boot logo in the BIOS settings.

Comment: @Blackwood thank you for your response. However, where exactly is that setting? In what section?

Comment: There are many different BIOS each with many versions. You would have to look around in yours to see if there is a setting to control the boot logo.

Comment: You may have misunderstood my question. I want the bootup and splash screen to stay the OEM. However, when Windows itself is loading, that is, when there is a loading icon under the OEM logo, I believe the BIOS is not enforcing that.

Comment: You're right. I misunderstood you question.

Comment: @Blackwood ok, so do you now have an answer now that you misunderstood my question?

Comment: Sorry. I don't.